# Why does my Python thread start when it shouldn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a testing script:

```
import threading
import time

isWaiting = 0

def wait():
    global isWaiting
    time.sleep(1)
    isWaiting = 0

myThread = threading.Thread(target=wait)

while True:
    if isWaiting == 0:
        print("Starting thread\n")
        isWaiting = 1
        myThread.start()
```

However, after the first second of waiting it breaks with the error that "threads can only be started once". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to create many threads while the first one is running or do you want to want to create only one thread?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are starting the same thread immediately without **joining** and **reinitializing** it.

```
import threading
import time

isWaiting = 0

def wait():
    global isWaiting
    time.sleep(1)
    isWaiting = 0

while True:
    if isWaiting == 0:
        myThread = threading.Thread(target=wait)
        print("Starting thread\n")
        isWaiting = 1
        myThread.start()
        myThread.join()
```

Things to be noted:

- You cannot reuse the same thread, initialize it again.
- If you want to run the threads in sequence, i.e. one after another, you have to `thread.join()` before starting another thread

Answer (score -1):

In the second that the thread is waiting, the loop runs again and `myThread.start()` is called again, but the thread is already running. You must either wait for the thread to finish (with `join`) or better use a synchronization object.